# Converting calendar dates to Chinese lunar dates in Google Sheets

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, calendar, chinese-locale

I'm trying to convert calendar dates to Chinese lunar dates in google sheets. But I have difficulties. It is easy to do in excel by using formula:

```
    `=TEXT(A2; "[$-130000]dd.mm.yy")`
```

[image: Screen from excel]

But it doesn't work in google sheets. So, how to convert calendar dates to Chinese lunar dates in google sheets?

Comment: see if it helps: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PfdrrGkMtFXmVBkaC3TBESzE-BRH1pzi5u8Qh5XAnHY/edit#gid=632229235

Comment: looks like its a paid job: https://www.upwork.com/freelance-jobs/apply/Looking-for-Google-Sheet-and-Presentation-Expert_~019255806a5ae3791e/

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=TEXT((REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(
 "http://en.nongli.info/convert/index.php?c=solar&year="&YEAR(A1)&"&month="&MONTH(A1)&"&date="&DAY(A1), 
 "//td[@colspan='2']"), "(.+\d+)")&" "&YEAR(A1))*1, "dd.mm.yy")
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/189qqSvaKetCvJitEbRJeRxCHhmtpTh9wEijS_sPZ81o/edit#gid=0)